# Shift of Schwartz function is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. For $M\in \mathbb{R}_+ $ consider the function
$$\tilde{\varphi}(x):=\sum_{y\in M\mathbb{Z}^d}\varphi(x+y).$$

Now I want to deduce
$ \; \bullet \tilde{\varphi}$ is well-defined
$ \; \bullet \tilde{\varphi}$ is M-periodic
$ \; \bullet \tilde{\varphi}$ is smooth
To address the first point we know that
any $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ there exists a constant $C_k>0$ s.t. for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^d$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$ we have
\begin{align*}
    |\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|\leq C_k(1+|x|)^{-k}.
\end{align*}
and thus we also know
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{y\in M\mathbb{Z}^d}|\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x+y)|\leq \sum_{y\in M\mathbb{Z}^d} C_k(1+|x+y|)^{-k}.
\end{align*}
If $M=1,x=0$ and for $k>d$ it is well-known that the right-hand side is summable. Ignoring the $M=1,x=0$ condition and choosing $k>d$ we get the well-definedness of the function. In that case it is also periodic. How does this follow in general? And how do we show smoothness? 
In the case $d=1, M>1, x\in [0,M]$ we can estimate
$$|\varphi(x+y)|\leq C (M+|x+y|)^{-2}\leq C(M-|x|+|y|)^-2\leq C(|y|)^{-2}.$$
The statement then follows by the Weierstraß-$M$-test.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: Fix $x$ and let $R>2|x|$ (if $x=0$ just set $R=2$ arbitrarily), then decompose the sum as
$$
\sum_{y\in M\mathbb{Z}}= \sum_{|y|\leq R} + \sum_{|y|>R}.
$$
The first one is fine, as it's a finite sum, for the other notice that for such a $y$ we have $|x+y|\geq |y|-|x|\geq |x|$, and so
$$
\sum_{|y|>R} (1+|x+y|)^{-k}\leq \sum_{|y|>R} (1+|x|)^{-k},
$$
and this last is always summable if we choose $k$ large enough.

Since this allows you to handle all derivatives as you mentioned, then we have that the function is smooth.

Comment: Hey, that's correct, thanks. But it doesn't deal with the multidimensional case since here we sum over $y\in M\mathbb{Z}^d$ and then it isn't clear to me how the Weierstraß M-test can be applied.

Comment: @Annie: Once you establish absolute convergence, it doesn't matter if you're in higher dimensions, since any rearrangement will give the same value.